# Signout with Firebase 5.6.0

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hope this post won't be marked as duplicate.
I'm doing a React app application and I implemented `firebase 5.6.0` in the project. I realized some functions returning promises which work properly on sign in and signup to firebase but not for the sign out.

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signOut), I just use `auth().signOut()` and it just returns a void promise.

By the way, calling this function doesn't perform any signOut.

What did I miss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know very well how firebase works under the hood, if there is a better way to perform the sign out and you want to share, you're welcome.

My previous function was like:

`export const logout = () => auth().signOut();`

Instead I solved doing like:

```
export const logout = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        auth()
          .signOut()
          .then(() => resolve(true));
      }
    });
  });
```